# Char Point Memory Allocation to reference address of C++ String?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, ascii, memory-address

I would like to convert an array of Integers
2, 3, 4, 8
5, 7, 9, 12
1, 0, 6, 10

to a string with the entries of that matrix appended in clockwise order
 “2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 10, 6, 0, 1, 5, 7, 9”.

**I have to keep declaration of `int * Matrix` and `char * OutBuffer` the way they are**

```
int main()
{
    int matrixArray[rowCount][columnCount] =
    {   {2, 3, 4, 8},
        {5, 7, 9, 12},
        {1, 0, 6, 10}};

    int * matrix;
    string prebuffer;
    char  * outBuffer;

    outBuffer = new (nothrow) char[24];
    matrix = &matrixArray[0][0];

    BuildStringFromMatrix(matrix, rowCount, columnCount, outBuffer);
}
```

I declare and address all my pointers before passing them in. However, I am not sure if I am going about allocating memory for the `outBuffer` to store the characters of prebuffer correctly?

```
void BuildStringFromMatrix(int* Matrix, int NumRows, int NumColumns, char * OutBuffer)
    {
        string prebuffer;
        bool stringLeft = true;
        int i = 0;

        while (stringLeft)
        {
            int clockwiseDir[12] = { 1,1,1,4,1,1,0,4,-4,-1,-1,-1 };

            prebuffer = to_string(Matrix[i]) + ", ";
            OutBuffer = new char [prebuffer.length() + 1];
            cout << prebuffer;
            i += clockwiseDir[i];

            if (i == 6)
            {
                prebuffer = to_string(Matrix[i]) + " ";
                cout << prebuffer;
                stringLeft = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

**When I do not implement `OutBuffer` I have no trouble accessing and printing the matrix in clockwise format

But I how would I go about using OutBuffer to reference and print prebuffers contents??
I need numbers to display not unprintable symbols on the ASCII table

Thanks in advance :)
**

Comment: `Matrix[j]` of course know nothing about `i`, so you cannot go to the second row.

Comment: You want your array in 2D character array ? Or in a single string variable ?

Comment: Converting your integer array into a printable string is a _string formatting problem_. You can't just cast one into the other and expect it to work - that only tells the compiler to pretend the conversion was already done. If you're supposed to populate the formatted string into `outBuffer`, you need to allocate some space first, and then write the formatted string into that space.

Comment: Oh, and once you've figured out how to use the built-in string formatting facilities (eg, `ostringstream`), you also need to think about how array indexing works.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, in your loop under `BuildStringFromMatrix` function you are not using your i value anywhere.
Second, matrix = matrixArray should do fine.